# Multiple function operation

Tags: android

I`m new in android studio...

I`m trying to create a calculator, but I have two basic problems...

first how can I define dot (or point) operation in **MainActivity.java**?

second is how can I break multiple functions (e.g. `25*3+45/4+sin(45)`)?

and the third one in just for fun: how can I show answers live in the second textview that I created for result?

like real-time answering?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10pt"
    android:layout_marginRight="10pt"
    android:layout_marginTop="3pt">
    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5pt"
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5pt"
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you know about postfix operation for parsing the equations?

Comment: What are you calling *dot* ?

Comment: @MohammedAtif - I`m just heard it, not use it. Can you explain it with an example?!! I will be thankful

Comment: @SimonPA using for decimalize numbers...

Comment: @rexo, its not easy as it look. I suggest you to see youtibe videos for infix to postfix conversion and solving equations